# how to fix no null constraint in django

Tags: python, django

I am creating a user using  `OneToOne` relationship , when I enter the data in the form and submit it, I'm getting no null constraint error

**view.py**

```
def registerUser(request):
    if request.method=='POST':
        form=UserCreationForm(request.POST)
        form_class=ProfileForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid() and form_class.is_valid():
            form.save()
            form_class.save()
            return redirect('/home/')
    else:
            form=UserCreationForm()
            form_class = ProfileForm()

    return render(request,'register.html',{'form':form,'form_class':form_class})
```

**form.py**

```
class Registerform(UserCreationForm):
    class Meta:
        model=User
        fields= ['username','first_name','last_name','password1','password2']

    def save(self, commit=True):
        user=super(Registerform, self).save(commit=False)
        user.first_name=self.cleaned_data['first_name']
        user.last_name = self.cleaned_data['last_name']

        if commit:
            user.save()
        return user


class ProfileForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = UserProfile
        fields = [ 'location']
```

**models.py**

```
class UserProfile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    description = models.TextField(max_length=500, blank=True)
    location = models.CharField(max_length=30, blank=True)
    birth_date = models.DateField(null=True, blank=True)
    salary=models.CharField(max_length=120)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.location
```

Comment: you should show us the entire error trace btw. Makes it easier to pinpoint what the exact error is and where it happens.

Comment: @dirkgrotenException Type: IntegrityError
Exception Value: 
NOT NULL constraint failed: try1_userprofile.user_id

Comment: @dirkgroten         Exception Type: IntegrityError
Exception Value: 
NOT NULL constraint failed: try1_userprofile.user_id

Answer (score 1):

Your `UserProfile` model requires a `salary` but your form only has a `location` field. So when your form is submitted with a `location`, it's valid, but the underlying model cannot be saved because `salary` will be `None`.

Add the `salary` field to your form, or make `salary` a nullable field.

Also, you need to assign the `user` field before saving the profile, since that also is not nullable. One way to do that is:

```
user = form.save()  # this is the UserForm so when saving it returns the user
profile = form_class.save(commit=False)
profile.user = user
profile.save()
```

I would recommend you carefully read the Django documentation on [model forms](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/forms/modelforms). The section on the [save method](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/forms/modelforms/#the-save-method) in particular would explain you how to properly handle these cases.